# Flutter: How To display Currency In Indian Numbering Format?

Tags: flutter

have a question about formatting the Rupee currency (Indian Rupee - INR).

For example, numbers here are represented as:

> 1
>
> 10
>
> 100
>
> 1,000
>
> 10,000
>
> 1,00,000
>
> 10,00,000
>
> 1,00,00,000
>
> 10,00,00,000

But not able to find any reference library where I can separate comma number in Indian formate.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [Intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl#number-formatting-and-parsing) package as follow:

```
    var format = NumberFormat.currency(locale: 'HI');
    print(format.format(100000000));//10,00,00,000.00
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped. I am curious to know why HI is used for India? Is it like Hindusthan?

Comment: HI = HINDI as I think

Comment: I am using NumberFormat.compactCurrency() as I want to compact it into lakhs, crores..etc. But, if I use 'HI' as the locale in it, it seems to print the lakh/crore in Hindi. I want to compact the currency but print lakh/crore in English. Do I need to use a different locale string for that? Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package as follow:

```
final indianRupeesFormat = NumberFormat.currency(
           name: "INR",
           locale: 'en_IN',
           decimalDigits: 0, // change it to get decimal places
           symbol: '₹ ',
        );
```

Or,
You can format any number as you want:

```
final numberFormatter = NumberFormat(
                            "##,##,###", 
                            "en_US",     // local US
                          )
```

An Extension to format numbers into Indian currency format:

```
extension RupeesFormatter on int {
     String inRupeesFormat() {
        return indianRupeesFormat.format(this);
     }
}
```

use it like this:

```
Text(
     2000.inRupeesFormat(),  // output:  ₹ 2,000
 ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Use locale 'en_IN' for English Indian formatting and 'HI' for Hindi Indian formatting

```
var indiaFormat = NumberFormat.compactCurrency(locale: 'HI');
print(indiaFormat.format(1000000));//10 लाख

var indiaFormat = NumberFormat.compactCurrency(locale: 'en_IN');
print(indiaFormat.format(1000000));//10L
```

Comment: but for 10000 it is showing like 10T (10 Thousand)....is there any possibility to get 10000 as 10k

Comment: @nagendranag I've not found any option to show them as 'k' instead of 'T' with Indian number format.

Answer (score 1):

`amount.toLocaleString('en-IN', {currency: 'INR', style: 'currency'})` is best jquery function to get Indian thousand comma seperator  Format

> toLocaleString

```js
 var amount="9887977998";

//if amount symbol required
console.log(addCommaSeperatorForAmt(amount,true))


function addCommaSeperatorForAmt(amount, symbolRequired) {
        var amountDigit = "";
        if (!symbolRequired) {
            amountDigit = Number(amount).toLocaleString('en-IN', {currency: 'INR', style: 'currency'}).replaceAll(/₹/g, "");
        } else {
            amountDigit = Number(amount).toLocaleString('en-IN', {currency: 'INR', style: 'currency'});
        }
        return amountDigit;
    }
```

Find this Ref:https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring.asp

Comment: if you want to remove currecy symbol.Then simply put `addCommaSeperatorForAmt(amount,false)` ,Thanks

Comment: If you want to change the currecy just refer the link i attched

Comment: you can convert any number in currency format as you want

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show amount with ₹ symbol then use the following code:

```
Text(
   NumberFormat.currency(
      symbol: '₹ ',
      locale: "HI",
      decimalDigits: 3,
   ).format(amount),
),
```

> Don't forget to import the [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package.